# Loading data in background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, firebase, asynchronous

Code

```
public class ContactSettings extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView contactsList;
private List<ContactsHelper> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private ContactsAdapter mAdapter;
   View rootView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_contact, container, false);



    contactsList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    //Add the data first
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    //and then create a object and pass the lis
    mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(contacts);

    contactsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    contactsList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    contactsList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    addDataToList();

}

public void addDataToList(){
ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
if (cursor != null) {
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id},
                        null);
                if (phoneCursor != null) {
                    if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        contacts.add(new ContactsHelper(name, phoneNumber));
                        phoneCursor.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

}

This fetches contacts from a users phone but takes time to open activity because of the load and i was advised to load it asynchronously but i have no idea about how it works. I looked upto some tutorials but still not sure. Can someone make this fragment to load data in the background and tell me whether its the same way to load data from firebase as well

Comment: There are multiple ways, easiest way is to use `AsyncTask` for this approach. Another is `Loader`.

Comment: As @JeelVankhede mentioned, look at [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

Comment: which is better loader or async task ? @basic

Comment: asynctask is much better u should use that one